# Parsing XML to data.frame in R

Tags: xml, r

Lots of questions on this, but can't find solution suiting this data format.  Grateful for advice on how to parse this:

```
<XML>
<constituency hansard_id="5" id="uk.org.publicwhip/cons/1" fromdate="1918" todate="9999-12-31">
    <name text="Aberavon"/>
</constituency>
<constituency hansard_id="6" id="uk.org.publicwhip/cons/2" fromdate="1997-05-01" todate="2005-05-04">
    <name text="Aberdeen Central"/>
</constituency>
<constituency hansard_id="7" id="uk.org.publicwhip/cons/3" fromdate="1885" todate="9999-12-31">
    <name text="Aberdeen North"/>
</constituency>
</XML>
```

The desired fields are evidently `c('hansard_id','id','fromdate','todate','name')`.  To read in and parse I've tried the following:

```
require(XML)
> indata = htmlParse('data.xml', isHTML=F)
> class(indata)
[1] "XMLInternalDocument" "XMLAbstractDocument"
> print(indata)
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<XML>
  <constituency hansard_id="5" id="uk.org.publicwhip/cons/1" fromdate="1918" todate="9999-12-31">
    <name text="Aberavon"/>
  </constituency>
  <constituency hansard_id="6" id="uk.org.publicwhip/cons/2" fromdate="1997-05-01" todate="2005-05-04">
    <name text="Aberdeen Central"/>
  </constituency>
  <constituency hansard_id="7" id="uk.org.publicwhip/cons/3" fromdate="1885" todate="9999-12-31">
    <name text="Aberdeen North"/>
  </constituency>
</XML>

> xmlToDataFrame(indata, stringsAsFactors=F)
  name
1     
2     
3
```

It's reading in ok, but `xmlToDataFrame` can't handle the format.  Is it because the data are attributes to the 'constituency' tag elements?  Very grateful for any guidance.

Comment: Use `do.call(rbind.data.frame,xpathApply(doc, "//*/constituency", xmlAttrs))`

Comment: Looks like sorcery to me, but thankfully works. Please paste as an answer and I'll close it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that `xmlToDataFrame` only access the `XML` nodes. For a given node the `xmlAttrs` function will return that nodes attributes. The `xpathApply` function takes a parsed xml document `doc` say and applies an `xpath` to it to get a set of nodes. Each of these nodes is then applied to a function which a user defines. The `xpath` `"//*/constituency"` will return all the `constituency` nodes in your document. We can then apply the `xmlAttrs` function to each:

```
res <- xpathApply(doc, "//*/constituency", xmlAttrs)
```

This will return us a list of attributes. We would like to bind these together for example:

```
rbind.data.frame(res[[1]], res[[2]], ...)
```

would bind the first and second, third, ... set of attributes together into a data.frame. A short way of doing this is to use the `do.call` function on out list of attributes:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, res)
```

will apply the row bind to all the elements of our list.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. It works fine until I have a <constituency> containing two <name> elements, and then I get vectors (ie. parsing the two tags separately) of different lengths. Is there a quick way to factor for that?

Comment: The `rbind.fill` function in the `plyr` package would allow you to bind with different lengths substituting NA's where appropriate.

Comment: Yes but wouldn't I need to extract a common id such as the `hansard_id` from the <constituency> tag when parsing the <name> tag with `xpathApply(doc, "//*/name", xmlAttrs)`?

Comment: In fact `rbind.fill` subs missing column data with NAs but there's no mention of missing rows (my problem).

Comment: `xpathSApply(doc, "//*/constituency/name", xmlGetAttr, 'text')` will give you the child `text` attribute to match your parent attributes. You can then use `row.names` to assign them to your `data.frame`. `xmlGetAttr` returns a named attribute in this case we give the name as `text`.

Comment: That returns empty string vectors. I suspect it's actually `xpathSApply(indata, "//*/constituency", xmlChildren)` I need, and to parse the resulting list of XMLNodeList objects.

Comment: Possibly or write a bespoke function to handle the nodes.

Comment: I shall experiment. Thanks jdharrison